# pinescript - how can i draw a line in first bar (barcolor)?

Tags: pine-script

i can't plot a line from the firts color bar, i'm doing something wrong for sure because it plots in every bar of the same color

what i have right now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVASq.png)

What i'm trying to achive:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FduZV.png)

The code:
/@version=4
study(title="XTL + TQR", shorttitle= "XTL", overlay=true)

```
//Expert Trend Locator (XTL)
len     = input(34, minval=1, title = "XTL Period")
hLmt    = input(34, title="Threshold Value", minval=10)

xtl_src = hlc3
XTL = cci(xtl_src,len)

bull = XTL > hLmt
bear = XTL < -hLmt
neutral = (XTL <= hLmt) and (XTL >= -hLmt)

upcolor = color.rgb(0, 135, 225)
dwncolor = color.rgb(255, 0, 0)
ntlcolor = color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 30)

barcolor(bull? upcolor : neutral? ntlcolor : dwncolor)

//tqr

range = high-low
tqr = 1.5
tqr2 = 0.5
tqr3 = 3
//bull

//bear

plot(bull? (low+range*tqr) : bear? (low-range*tqr2) : na , color = color.white, style = 
plot.style_cross)
plot(bull? (low-range*tqr2) : bear? (low+range*tqr) : na, color = color.red, style = 
plot.style_cross)
plot(bull? (low+range*tqr3) : bear? (low-range*tqr3) : na , color = color.yellow, style = 
plot.style_cross)
```

Answer (score 1):

It has a ternary on the plot. use it

```
plot(bull? long : bear? short : na , color = color.white, style = plot.style_cross)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [valuewhen](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_valuewhen)

```
long = valuewhen (bull and not bull[1],low+range*tqr,0 )
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gustavo, it worked! but the lines continues to draw until the same color appears again, how can i delete the line when a white candle appears (or a red candle appears?) so it don't overlap with the other lines? Thanks for your help